# auto and static_casts - good practice

Tags: c++, c++11, coding-style

In the Scott Meyer's book Effective Modern C++ we can read, that:

```
std::vector<bool> features(const Widget& w);
Widget w;
…
bool highPriority = features(w)[5];
…
processWidget(w, highPriority);
```

and an option with auto

```
auto highPriority = features(w)[5];
```

which causes undefined behavior, because of the fact, that `features()` is returning `std::vector<bool>`, that uses proxy Object of type `std::vector<bool>::reference` when returning a value from `opearator[]`.

As a solution to this is adviced not to stop using `auto`, but using `static_casts`.

So Scott Meyers advice to use:

```
auto highPriority = static_cast<bool>(features(w)[5]);
```

instead of:

```
bool highPriority = features(w)[5];
```

My question is:
What is a real difference between those two? In my opinion both are the same, because both methods make refactoring harder in exactly the same way (changing return value type in the function features does not make variable highPriority a different type) and second one is shorter to write.

Comment: Just a suspicion, but off the top of my head I can't think of a functional difference, and Scott's only reason may be consistency - has he not advocated using `auto x = ` for practical everything somewhere in the same book...?  (Or maybe it was some online article I saw...)

Comment: @TonyD Yeah, consistency is probably the reason. He suggests to "prefer `auto` to explicit type declarations" in Item 5

Comment: I'd say the first solution explicitly tells the reader "the thing is not a bool, but I want it to be a bool". The second solution usually tells the reader "that is a bool or can at least be used as such" but the problem is that most readers read it as "that is a bool" and probably "hey, now we have `auto`, so we write it `auto highPriority = features(w)[5];`!", and boom. Even if both solutions are technically identical, the reader is warned in the first that there might be a problem with using `features(w)[5]` directly. By the way, the same problem occures with stuff like expression templates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't like the interface of `features`, you can hide the ugliness in a helper function

```
bool is_high_priority(const Widget& w)
{ return features(w)[5]; }
```

and now your

```
auto highPriority = is_high_priority(w);
```

works as expected.

Comment: Could you tell me where is !! Coming from? Is it some new operator or something? Is it a compiler specific feature? I somehow cannor find it anywhere

Comment: It is just two negations in a row. `!x` will turn `x` into a `bool` (by comparing it against 0), but with the opposite value. `!!x` will again invert the value of `!x`, producing `false` for zero and `true` for non-zero.

Answer (score 5):

With `features` a function that returns a `std::vector<bool>`,

```
auto highPriority = features(w)[5];
```

stores a logical reference. The stored object refers to a vector that no longer exists. Using it then incurs Undefined Behavior.

Instead do

```
bool const highPriority = features(w)[5];
```

or

```
auto const highPriority = !!features(w)[5];
```

or, as Scott recommends – but it's far too verbose for my taste – use a `static_cast`.

The stored object is now a `bool`.

There's no functional difference between these three ways of expressing the same declaration. The only differences are non-functional: the in my opinion needless verbosity of the `static_cast`, and a possibility that the `!!` may suppress a silly-warning about performance, from one common compiler.

Answer (score 0):

When you use auto, auto deduces it as the type returned by highPriority which is a reference to a bool. The thing is, highPriority does not return a reference to a bool but a std::vector::reference object. ('reference' is a nested class inside std::vector). std::vector::reference is a "proxy class", a class that emulates the behavior of some other type. Not only is it a proxy class but an "invisible" proxy class. Such classes do not work well with auto. Auto can't properly deduce the type of an invisible proxy class. But static_cast forces a high priority conversion into a bool. This avoids undefined behavior.

Comment: that's what I said. I asked for 2 possible solutions and why Scott Meyers prefers first one

Comment: He doesn't prefer it. There is a difference. His words... 

"the cast changes the type of the expression to bool, which auto then deduces as the type for highPriority. At runtime, the std::vector<bool>::reference object returned from std::vector<bool>::operator[] executes the conversion to bool that it supports..."

So the static cast is necessary for changing the type into a bool FIRST for all the rest to happen.

Comment: exactly the same cast is executed, when you say `bool highPrio...` In first and second attempt there is no difference in execution. In both solutions cast is made and it's the same cast. One is explicit one is implicit that's the only difference. Result is the same.